# pipenv install --system but only for user

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

I can use `pip install xx --user` to install packages for my user. When using pipenv, I can use `pipenv install --system` to not create a virtual environment but install the requirements on the system, but how can I tell pipenv to use the pip --user flag and install the required packages also only for my current user?

Another question could be, how can I use simple `pip` to install all requirements from Pipfile?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the environment variables

```
PIP_USER=1
PIPENV_SYSTEM=1
```

and running

```
pipenv install
```

will install the `Pipfile` packages to the user's system. As hinted in the question, it is `pip` that handles installing for a user (the install location), and `pipenv` that handles installing to the system (the install method).

Note that:

> pip’s command line options can be set with environment variables using the format `PIP_<UPPER_LONG_NAME>` . Dashes (`-`) have to be replaced with underscores (`_`).

From the pip [User Guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#environment-variables)

To install `Pipfile` requirements using standalone `pip`, you could [generate a `requirements.txt`](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/advanced/#generating-a-requirements-txt) using

```
pipenv lock -r [--dev]
```